# Show another Div when I clicked the button on the Previous Div

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-hide, angularjs-ng-show

I have two `<div>` in my html file. The first `<div>` contains a button that when I click should show the other div and would hide the first one. My code is something like this:

```
<div class="container" ng-hide="showme">
    <p>Quick</p>
    <button class="button" ng-click="showme=true" >Edit</button>
</div>
<div class="container" ng-show="showme">
    <p>Congratulations!</p>
</div>
```

How can I possibly do that?

Comment: Do you have any javascript?

Comment: @JoeyWood I dont have javascript yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier with jquery 
just write

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Button-id").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().css("display","none");
            $(this).parent().next().css("display","block");
        });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sy1x1xm9/

Comment: Thanks this works but I forgot to mention that I am using angularjs. Btw, I can use this tho but it seems that the javascript was calling the class of the button, I have several buttons with the same class, I tried adding id and the called the id on the javascript but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Sorry i am an angularjs beginner

Comment: Its ok, I can use this but when I add an id and used it in javascript intead of the class, It does not work.

Comment: Yes I added an id and used it in the javascript but it doesnt work https://jsfiddle.net/gsmwb4gn/

Comment: here is another fiddle with id https://jsfiddle.net/alexGeni/6j7Lpgyd/1/

Comment: you just forgot to change the dot for #

Comment: ow okay Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable in your javascript.

```
var showme = false;
```

Then add a button onclick that updates the showme value

Answer (score 0):

your code seem nothing wrong ,so whats your problem? the `showme` which bind to `ng-show` means the `$scope.showme`,and you need to inject the `$scope` in your controller if you want to show your button init.you should define `$scope.showme = true`

Comment: you can see thie code [code address](http://plnkr.co/edit/a39tguEWwb0jGACkp6vE?p=info)

Comment: why is this not working on ,y codes? I have declared scope showme in my controller and declared it as false but this is still not working

Comment: are there any errors in your console? maybe the other problem.I need your whole code of JS and HTML

Comment: without the real code,I can't figure out the problem,can you put up a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Set showme as scope variable in your controller or directive whichever is used as

$scope.showme = true;

Then use this scope variable in the view to update the dom:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <div class="container" ng-hide="showme">
            <p>Quick</p>
            <button class="button" ng-click="showme=true">Edit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="container" ng-show="showme">
            <p>Congratulations!</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

          $scope.show = true;
    });
    </script>
```

Hope this helps